# Removing an Item from a LinkedList

Tags: ruby, data-structures, linked-list, backend, variable-assignment

I am trying to make a LinkedList assignment on ruby and was facing difficulties to do the **remove method**, so I searched in google and got the code from the **remove method**.
What I can't understand is the logic behind it, I can't understand how it works, how it works the logic to delete it.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
      @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end

class LinkedList
  def add(number)
    new_node = Node.new(number)

    if @head.nil?           

        @head = new_node
          @tail = new_node
      else
          @tail.next_node = new_node
          @tail = new_node
      end
  end

  def get(index)
    #your code here
    node = @head
    while index > 0 && node
      node = node.next_node
      index -= 1
    end
    node.value
  end

  def add_at (index, number)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = Node.new(number)
      @tail = Node.new(number)
    else
        first = @head
        index -= 1
        while index > 0 && first
                first = first.next_node
                index -= 1
        end
        old_next = first.next_node
        first.next_node = Node.new(number)
        first.next_node.next_node = old_next
    end
  end

  def remove (index)
    node = @head
    index -= 1
    while index > 0 && node
      node = node.next_node
      index -= 1
    end
    node.next_node = node.next_node.next_node
  end
end
```

Comment: Suppose you are in a line-up where each person in line is expected to know who is in front of them and who is behind them. Suppose "Mary" is behind you and "Daisy" is in front of you. If you must leave the line there are two things you must do: tell "Daisy" that henceforth "Mary" will be behind her and tell "Mary" that henceforth "Daisy" will be in front of her. The adjustments that must be made to a doubly-linked list when a link is removed are analogous.

Comment: ...Of course, if you are at the front of the line you need only tell the person behind you that they are now at the front of the line, and if you are at the end of the line you need only tell the person ahead of you that they are now at the end of the line.

Comment: Ok, so in your example, Mary 'lose the track' of me and get Daisy address, being like I was never there then?

Comment: Yes, or let's say when a link has been removed from a linked list we forget about that link.

Comment: Cool, now I got it. Thanks!